# a compact set with nonempty convex sections

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $X = [0,1]^d$ be the unit cube in the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space.
For every $x \in X$ and every coordinate $i=1,2,\ldots,d$ denote by $x_{-i} := (x_j)_{j \neq i}$.
Given a set $Y \subseteq X$ and a vector $x_{-i} \in [0,1]^{d-1}$ denote by $Y_{x_{-i}} := \{(x_i,x_{-i}) \in Y \colon x_i \in [0,1]\}$ the $x_{-i}$-section of $Y$.
Let $Y \subseteq X$ be a compact set that satisfies the following condition: for every $x \in X$ and every coordinate $i=1,2,\ldots,d$, the $x_{-i}$-section $Y_{x_{-i}}$ is nonempty and convex.
Is it true that the set $Y$ is contractible?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that each $Y_{x_{-i}}$ is a line segment? If so, I suggest to do define sections as follows. For $i = 1,\ldots,d$ let $p_i : [0,1]^d \to   [0,1]^{d-1}$ denote the projection obtained by omitting the $i$-th coordinate. For $z \in  [0,1]^{d-1}$ let

$$Y_{i,z} = Y \cap p_i^{-1}(z) .$$

Comment: Indeed, Paul, your representation is equivalent to the one I provided.